# How do I get my context menu to appear in a certain place?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I'm in Visual Studio using c#. I have a label element that I'm trying to get to act as a toolbox. I added

```
contextMenuStrip1.Show();
```

to the `mousedown` event, so that my context menu pops with all the tools on it. It shows up in the very top left of the screen though. As a note, that's the default position, but if I do right click it into existence, left click then just gives it in the last place it was set from right clicking. I basically just want the left click to give the same behavior of the right click, and have no clue of what parameters to set to cause that to happen.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7z41k67k(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the parameters that pass the control and the mouse location:

```
void label1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
  if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left) {
    contextMenuStrip1.Show(label1, e.Location);
  }
}
```